# Responsive design layout CSS menu position overlaps header logo

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want it so when the window is `800px` wide or below it hides the menu `<div>` and shows the *menu icon* ☰ and upon clicking the icon I want the menu to appear in a neat layout so that an iPhone can view it at `320px`,

This is my current HTML.

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <p>LOGO HERE</p>
        </div><!--logo-->
        <div id="menu_wrapper">
            <ul id="nav">
                <div id="homeBtn"><a href="index.php"><span id="homeBtnImg"></span></a></div>
                <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="end"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--wrap-->
</div><!--header-->
```

[image: example design]

Also as a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k26LT/)

Comment: You keep breakign the thing how? How is it supposed to look like? You should give us an example because a 'neat layout' can be anything..

Comment: Updated my answer based on the design image.

Comment: Edited question, please revert if this is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the problem enough to offer a solution.

Absolutely positioned and floating elements can overlap. When clicking on the ☰ the element is given `float: right` which will also give the element `display: block`; this means that it takes up `100%` of the width and pushes the whole vertical navigation leftwards towards the logo. A further problem arises in that the `#logo` is rendered over the top of the menu (the `z-index` here is not working), so the ☰ is no longer sees the *click* due to another element being rendered over the top.

`z-index` is not working because positioned elements create a new stacking context - see http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/ for more information about this.

The CSS `float` should not be needed here and could be replaced with `inline-block` or `table-cell` display values. I have also removed `z-index` in my demo.

Finally, I have changed the `$(window).resize()` calculation to remove the *vertical navigation* class at the same width as the `@media` query since there was `100px` of width when a previously vertical menu could disappear before changing to a horizontal one.

**Updated answer** (based on requested [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bRJJ.png))

With the added information, this solution can be much cleaner and I can also remove the `display: table-cell` from the original answer (left in below).

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDqJz/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <p>LOGO HERE</p>
        <span id="menu">&#9776;</span>
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="homeBtn"><a href="index.php"><span id="homeBtnImg"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-color: #f06060;
    padding: 52px 0px;
}
#logo {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 348px;
    height: 57px;
    border:1px dotted black;
    position:relative;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    display:none;
}
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav.vertical {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#nav.vertical li {
    display: list-item;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#nav li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #menu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

Same as original answer below.

---

**Original answer**

See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDqJz/2/) or the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <p>LOGO HERE</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_wrapper">
            <div id="menu">&#9776;</div>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li id="homeBtn"><a href="index.php"><span id="homeBtnImg"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    background-color: #f06060;
    padding: 52px 0px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#wrap {
    display:table-row;
}
#logo {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 338px;
    height: 57px;
}
#menu {
    display:none;
}
#menu_wrapper {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5px;
}
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav.vertical {
    display: block;
}
#nav.vertical li {
    display: list-item;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#nav li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #menu {
        display: block;
    }
    #nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        $("#nav").removeClass('vertical');
    }
});

$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggleClass('vertical');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: for some reason my menu icon isnt activating the menu ?

http://www.real-creative.co.uk/new/demo3.php

Comment: Which browser are you using? It is working for me in Chrome 31

Answer (score 1):

You should use media queries. something like this:

> ```
> #menu_wrapper{ 
> /* menu style */ 
> }
> #logo{ 
> /* logo style */ 
> display:none;
> }
> @media (max-width: 800px) {
>   #menu_wrapper { display:none }
>   #logo { display:block }
> }
> ```